# how to save the 'user' object that not used to insert it everytime you need it using django

Tags: python, django

i want to do these thing:

1.open the `login_view` (which is the page user login)

2.write my username and password , and put 'login' button, then submit to the `login_submit` view

3.in `login_submit` view , if your username and password are right , you will return to the homepage

4.but when i `return HttpResponseRedirect("/")`  to the hpmeage,  the `homepage.html`(the following code)  does not has a `user` object

5.i have to make it like this in `login_submit` view:

`return render_to_response('homepage.html',{'user':user})`

6.that is Cumbersome , i want to use `return HttpResponseRedirect("/")` , so should i set a cookies that save the user , or has any other easy way to save user that  not used to insert it everytime you need it .

thanks

the homepage.html is :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please <a href="/account/login_view">login</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

the homepage virw is :

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('homepage.html')
```

this is login_view :

```
def login_view(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = LoginForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = LoginForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('accounts/login_view.html',{'form': form,})
```

the login_view.html is :

```
<form action="/account/login_submit/" method="post">
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="login" /> or <a href="/account/register_view"><input type="button" value="register"></a></p>
</form>
```

and

```
def login_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  
        if user is not None:  
            if user.is_active:  
               login(request, user)
               return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
            else:
               return HttpResponse('user is not active')
        else:
            #return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/login_submit") 
            return HttpResponse('login error')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).